# Nhibernate throws "Can't resolve property exception"

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I have an entity Program with following mapping.

```
References(c => c.Region).Column("FK_RegionId").Fetch.Join();
References(c => c.RequestType).Column("FK_RequestTypeId ").Fetch.Join();
References(c => c.CategoryCode).Column("FK_CategoryCodeId").Fetch.Join();
References(c => c.HouseHoldSize).Column("FK_HouseHoldSizeId").Fetch.Join();
```

And I am trying to fetch using following Hibernate query

```
return session.QueryOver<Program>().Where(x => x.Region.ID == fields.Region && x.RequestType.ID == fields.RequestType
            && x.HouseHoldSize.Size == fields.HouseholdSize).SingleOrDefault();
```

But it throws exception saying it cannot resolve the property HouseHoldSize.Size. Can anyone elaborate whats happening..? Thanks in advance:)

Comment: My guess was wrong and so I have deleted my previous answer. But your comment on it let know you have found at least a partial solution. I think you should [edit] your question to add it in it as a not good enough solution and tell it still does not address all your concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use a property of another entity without a join.  You have to use a join if you are using `QueryOver`.  You can do this with the linq provider though:

```
return session.Query<Program>().Where(x => x.Region.ID == fields.Region && x.RequestType.ID == fields.RequestType
        && x.HouseHoldSize.Size == fields.HouseholdSize).SingleOrDefault();
```

If you want to use queryover take a look at:

http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.html

Comment: I think I already added a comment for that. But anyways, the problem was solved using "JoinQueryOver" in Nhibernate. I just want to know why "Fetch.Join()" won't work...

Comment: That's not really what your question asked.  `Fetch.Join()` is only used for "eager" loading data from the mapping side.  Even though it is eager loaded you still can't use properties from another entity in `QueryOver`.  You have to use the linq provider to do this or do explicit joins in `QueryOver`